# WCF DataContract With List of RegExs Won't Serialize Properly

Tags: regex, wcf, serialization, datacontract, datamember

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class InboundMailbox
{
    public const char EmailSeparator = ';';

    [DataMember]
    public string POP3Host { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string WebServiceURL { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Regex> Allowed { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Regex> Disallowed { get; set; }
}
```

If `Allowed` and `Disallowed` are empty then it serializes just fine across my WCF service. As soon as one of those lists contains a value, I get this in a CommunicationException:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:00:29.9899990'.

Why is it giving me a hard time about serializing those two properties? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big are the list of Regexes you are sending across the wire?

Comment: If I put a single regex in one of the lists I get the exception. And the regexes themselves are not that long, probably < 20 chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Regex` class implements the `ISerializable` interface, which means that it's serialized as a property bag (dictionary of string/object). Looking at the implementation of `ISerializable.GetObjectData` for the `Regex` class in Reflector, it shows that it serializes both the pattern (string) and the options (of type `RegexOptions`). Since the type is `ISerializable`, WCF doesn't *know* about `RegexOptions`, so it will fail to serialize this type.

One simple solution is to simply "tell" WCF that this is a *known type*, so the serialization will work (an easy place to declare it is using the `[KnownType]` attribute in the `InboundMailbox` class (see below). Another option would be to have the data member as the regex pattern instead of the `Regex` itself (and possibly the options as well).

```
public class StackOverflow_7909261
{
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(RegexOptions))]
    public class InboundMailbox
    {
        public const char EmailSeparator = ';';

        [DataMember]
        public string POP3Host { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string WebServiceURL { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Regex> Allowed { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Regex> Disallowed { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        InboundMailbox obj = new InboundMailbox
        {
            POP3Host = "popHost",
            EmailId = "email",
            WebServiceURL = "http://web.service",
            Allowed = new List<Regex>
            {
                new Regex("abcdef", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase),
            },
            Disallowed = null,
        };
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(InboundMailbox));
        try
        {
            dcs.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you'd find out the error if you had enabled tracing on the server side; it would have an exception saying that the type `RegexOptions` wasn't expected.

Comment: Did you ever know that you're my hero, and everything I would like to be? I can fly higher than an eagle, 'cause you are the wind beneath my wings.